# How to load data into scroll view after saving -

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I've made a simple save and load app for contacts (first name, second name and phone number) using NSUserDefaults but i need to show this information in a scroll view. could someone please guide me how to do this? code for each IBAction is this:

//this is to save a contact - where does it go? trying to figure that out...

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSString*saveString = firstName.text;
    NSUserDefaults  *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"saveString"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

this is to load the last contact that was saved. where does it load from, i don't know. how to add to it dynamically, need to figure that out. how to log everything on a UIScrollView, pls advise!

```
- (IBAction)load:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveString"];
    [firstName setText:loadString];
    NSLog(@"%@", theArray);
```

basically i need to make a simple phoneBook app for class and make the contact show up as a button on a scroll view once saved. everything works fine except for making contact show up as a button!

Comment: Why a button on a scroll view? Why not a row in a table view? If scroll view, what have you researched / read / tried ?

Comment: You should also look in to Core Data if you are going to be saving a lot of information.

Comment: i had approached it in the wrong way, we have to put a mutableDictionary inside a mutableArray, give it 3 fields (name, phone number and email) and everytime i added a new contact it would make a new button:

Comment: -(void)makeButton

{
    int yLocation = 20;
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<informationArr.count; i++)